# Android project can't connect to WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf

I need to use .Net wcf web service. but I can't success it. I saw error and it is written:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:0 in java.io.InputStreamReader@46029560)
```

Can you help me how I use this web service?

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="Service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
<xs:element name="GetTreatmentValues">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tID" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">...</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">...</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">...</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IService_GetTreatmentValues_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTreatmentValues"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IService_GetTreatmentValues_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetTreatmentValuesResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetTreatmentValues">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetTreatmentValues" message="tns:IService_GetTreatmentValues_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetTreatmentValuesResponse" message="tns:IService_GetTreatmentValues_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" type="tns:IService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetTreatmentValues">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetTreatmentValues" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.2.7:90/Service.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My android

```
private final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
private final String SOAPACTION="http://tempuri.org/GetTreatmentValues";
private final String METHODNAME="GetTreatmentValues";

private final String URL="http://192.168.2.7:90/IService/Service.svc?singleWsdl";

private EditText text1;
private EditText text2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tansiyon);

     Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHODNAME);
            request.addProperty("tID",1);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope sp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            sp.dotNet = true; 
            sp.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {

                aht.call(SOAPACTION,sp);

                text2.setText("test");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                text2.setText("error");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: I use [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) to communicate with wcf services, it may be helpful for you too.

Comment: I also use ksoap2. But not connect.

Answer (score 0):

first off, I assume you didn't forget to add suitable permissions in your app's manifest.

now you have a couple of problems, first you are trying network access in the UI thread which is not allowed by Android for API 12 and up, I expect a "network on main thread exception" to appear in your LogCat. You just have to move the ksoap2 call to an AsyncTask or so.

the other problem which I faced before is that I didn't specify a namespace in my wcf web service, so tempuri.org is put by default and it was not working, I had to change it to something else and use it and then it worked like a charm.

try to solve the first problem and run the app, you may not have a problem with tempuri.org but if it still crash then change the namespace in your service, publish it and run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

In the android code don't append ?WSDL. Just write address up to Service.svc or you can copy the address from  <soap:address location="..."/> tag of WSDL file. I hope it might work for you.

Refer the following link for further details:

http://techzusiastic.blogspot.in/2014/11/solved-xmlpullparse-error-problem-while.html

Comment: good info, but maybe providing a snippet of code that illustrates what you have explained would be more helpful

Comment: Please refer my post @                     http://techzusiastic.blogspot.in/2014/11/solved-xmlpullparse-error-problem-while.html    For the code snippet

Comment: This site is meant to be useful for questions now...and in the future. If that link stops working today, tomorrow, next week, next year...your answer is useless. Also, why as someone coming to this site for an answer, would I want to go off to another site to see the code?

Comment: In the code of android I think only one line should be be changed it. i.e instead of String url ="http://192.168.2.7:90/IService/Service.svc?wsdl" String url ="http://192.168.2.7:90/IService/Service.svc"  should be mentioned.